# White screen flickering issue when page is loaded - React - SSR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, serverside-javascript, server-side-rendering

I am facing an issue in my React Web App. I am using Server-side rendering and redux with React.

Here is what happens:

1. Request for a page (let's say `/about`)
2. Browser loads and renders the server side document content (since i am using SSR).
3. A white screen appears for a second and less, and then the complete page renders/painted.
4. When i say complete page renders and painted. I mean, the complete page content (document) is not being generated at server side (as a part of SSR). There is some content (part of a document) being generated at the client side as well.

So initially i see the server-side generated html, then a white screen, then the complete web page.

Can anyone help me out narrowing down this issue or someone has faced similar issue having a solution to fix this problem. Let me know if i have to share more information.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this problem? Which I'm also facing.

Comment: @Gab - Yes, Two things can help you solve this problem. 1. Make sure you don't hydrate partial HTML document from the server (SSR). The complete document is SSR. If doing that doesn't solve your problem, 2. try moving your external CSS to inline CSS. Let me know if it solves your problem as well. I will add all this to an answer.

Comment: getting same issue only with IE. Any updates?

Comment: @jeremymarc Please try the solution provided in the comment above and let me know if that helps you in your case.